# C# vs PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, class, reflector, folderbrowserdialog

I'm trying to re-write a C# script in PowerShell. I'm figuring it out piece by piece.

The PowerShell version is telling me 'Cannot find an overload for "Call" and the argument count: "2".'. So I know it's because PS is requiring that the 3rd parameter be present. But, why doesn't the C# require it? Because of the "params"?

What does the params even mean or do in this context?
How can I mimic that in PowerShell?

Yes, I left out a lot of code because I didn't feel it pertained to my issue of not understanding what's going on with this particular error.

C#

```
object dialog = r.Call(ofd, "CreateVistaDialog")

public class Reflector
{
    public object Call(object obj, string func, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return Call2(obj, func, parameters);
    }
}
```

PowerShell

```
$Dialog = $Reflector.Call($This.OFD, "CreateVistaDialog")

Class Reflector
{
    [Object]Call([Object]$Obj, [String]$Func, [Object[]]$Parameters)
    {
        return $This.Call2($Obj, $Func, $Parameters)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C# `Call` `parameters` is an optional `params` type.
In your Powershell class, `Call` has three required parameters, `$Parameters` is not optional.

It looks like you could omit that parameter in your Powershell script since your not using it but I can't say whether `Call2` uses it or not. You may just want to change the signatures of both methods in your Powershell script.